# DFP not serving Ads for Google Nexus7 using SmartBanner

Tags: android, nexus-7, google-dfp

I am using DFP in Android. It is delivering ads for mobile emulators but it is not delivering the ads for `Google Nexus 7` (`1920x1200`  with `320 dpi`) device.

Below is the code which I am using.

```
final FrameLayout adLayout = (FrameLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.frame_layout_adView);
        PublisherAdView adView = new PublisherAdView(activity);
        adView.setAdUnitId(adUnitId);
        adView.setAdSizes(AdSize.SMART_BANNER);
        adView.setAdListener(new DFPAdvertisementListener(adView, adLayout)); //Set the AdListener to listen for standard ad events.
        adLayout.addView(adView); //Add the adView to it.
        adView.loadAd(new PublisherAdRequest.Builder().build());
```

Order Sizes which I am using in DFP server is below.

`320x50`
`360x50`
`468x50`
`720x107`
`728x90`
`768x90`
`800x90`

But none of them is delivering in the app. It simply says noFill from server.

But the ads are delivering if I test in the Google Nexus 7 (`1920x1200`  with `240 dpi`).

Please advice me to fix it.

Comment: What is `onAdFailedToLoad()` reporting? Also, have you tried calling `addTestDevice()` on the Builder?

Comment: It showed there is no fill from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed this problem. The real issue is The nexus and Kindle fire devices are converting the uploaded images into 2x density. Then it gives the exact support.

Cheers.

Comment: Could you please suggest the exact height and width for Nexus7 device? I am also facing the similar issue and I can't fix it. Please help.